# CakePHP Encrypt URL

Tags: cakephp, encryption

I am trying to encrypt the URL being passed in CakePHP. I followed this article (http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/yuri.salame/2008/07/15/encrypting-urls#), and it does not work. I know this is an old article. I am using CakePHP 2.x

Here are the errors shown :

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: url [APP/webroot/index.php, line 108]
Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to Dispatcher::dispatch() must be an instance of CakeRequest, null given, called in /home/xxx/domains/xxx.com/public_html/xxx/v3/app/webroot/index.php on line 110 and defined [CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 140]
Warning (4096): Argument 2 passed to Dispatcher::dispatch() must be an instance of CakeResponse, none given, called in /home/xxx/domains/xxx.com/public_html/xxx/v3/app/webroot/index.php on line 110 and defined [CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 140]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [CORE/Cake/Routing/Filter/AssetDispatcher.php, line 45]
```

My **app/webroot/index.php** is (I am only showing the last part) :

```
App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing');

$url = do_decrypt($_REQUEST["url"]); 
$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher(); 
$Dispatcher->dispatch($url);

$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
$Dispatcher->dispatch(
    new CakeRequest(),
    new CakeResponse()
);
```

Comment: Where's the encryption? The article you linked to only encode the URL as base64, which is not a crypto system. Base64 has nothing to do with security.

Answer (score 1):

The `.htaccess` file that's coming with CakePHP has been changed in CakePHP 2.x. It no longer sets an `url` variable and hence it is not available in `$_REQUEST`. Instead, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the url. This url then has to be passed to the constructor of `CakeRequest`. So your code will look like:

```
App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing');

$url = do_decrypt($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
$Dispatcher->dispatch(
    new CakeRequest($url),
    new CakeResponse()
);
```

Comment: This snippet is for `app/webroot/index.php`

Comment: I tried this peace of code in my index.php but I don't see any change in URL navigator it still ./controller/action !!!